# Solving an equation with absolute values: $ | 2x - 5| + | 2x - 3 | = m $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

> Given that the following equation does not have solutions in  $\mathbb{R}$,       find the value of $m$:
>   $$| 2x - 5| + | 2x - 3 | = m $$

I try to resolve this equation on cases, when $| 2x - 5|$, $| 2x - 3 |$ are positive and negative. In two cases I can reduce $2x$ and then $m = \{ -8; 2 \}$, but I don't  know if it is correct.

Comment: If for example $\;x\ge\frac52\;$ , then the left side is $2x-5+2x-3=4x-8\;$ , so how do you dispose of $\;x\;$ ?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz, it also is foggy to me.

Comment: @Dora Benzo, what **exactly** are you supposed to do here? Usually one needs to solve *for $\;x\;$* ...

Comment: @DoraBenzo: See this plot http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%282x+-+5%29+%2B+abs%282x+-+3%29%2C+%28x%2C+-3%2C+7%29. You have three ranges to consider.

Comment: Note, if points $A$ and $B$ on the number line have coordinates $a$ and $b$ respectively, then an equation of the segment $\overline{AB}$ is 
$$|a-x| + |x-b| = |a-b|$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute for a moment $y=2x$. Then you need to solve $|y-5|+|y-3|= m$.

Now for every $y \in [3,5]$ we have $|y-5|+|y-3|=2$, and so, if $m=2$,then every $y\in [3,5]$ is a solution.

For $y >5$ we have $m = |y-5|+|y-3| = (y-5)+ (y-3)=2y-8 \geq 2$, and so $y=m/2+4$
Similarly, for $y<3$ we have $m = |y-5|+|y-3| = (3-y)+ (5-y)=8-2y \geq 2$, and so $y=+4-m/2$

Therefore, for $m>2$ you have two solutions $x = y/2 \in \{m/4+2, 2-m/4\}$.
For $m=2$ the solutions are $x \in [1.5,2.]$.
For $m < 2$ there is no solution

Answer (score 2):

We give a solution that is more detailed than necessary to find the answer.

Cases sound good. There are $3$ of them: (i) $x\lt \frac{3}{2}$; $\frac{3}{2}\le x\le \frac{5}{2}$; (iii) $x\gt \frac{5}{2}$.

In Case (i), both items inside the absolute value signs are negative, so the absolute values are $3-2x$ and $5-2x$ respectively, giving sum $8-4x$.

In Case (ii), the absolute values are $2x-3$ and $5-2x$ respectively, for sum $2$.

In Case (iii), the sum of the absolute values is $4x-8$.

Draw the graph of $y=|2x-3|+|2x-5|$.  For $x\lt \frac{3}{2}$ we are looking at $y=8-4x$, a line with negative slope. Then our function is steadily $2$ for a while. Finally, past $\frac{5}{2}$, we are on the line $y=4x-8$ with positive slope.  So down, then steady at $2$, then up.

Thus our function does not take on any values $\lt 2$. It does take on every value $\ge 2$.

The values of $m$ for which the equation has no solution are all $m\lt 2$.